# How does the grep operator work?

Tags: perl, hash, grep

I have an array and an hash. I'd like to match the key of the hash with the elements of the array.

I found an expression to grep all of the keys which matches with the array. It works, but I'm not sure that I've understood how it works. Can you explain what does it happen after `grep`?

Array `@text` and hash `%sys` are already defined.

```
my @new_array = grep { exists $sys{$_} ? $sys{$_} : 0 } @text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you found is over-complicated. It could/should be*:

```
my @new_array = grep { $sys{$_} } @text;
```

The `grep` function processes a list - in this case the contents of `@text` array - into a new list that only includes elements where the expression in the middle evaluates to a true value. The default value `$_` is set to each list item in turn so that the expression can take account of the list contents.

The expression in your example includes a ternary operator `?` which evaluates to the item before the `:` if the first part is true, or the value after it if false. So, in your case, it checks whether each key is in the `%sys` hash, and evaluates to a lookup of the hash entry if it exists, or 0 (a false value) if it does not. Functionally inside a `grep` this should be identical to just `$sys{$_}` because `undef` that you get from looking up the value of a non-existing key is also a false value.

---

`*` However, there is a caveat - if `%sys` was tied to a Perl class and had some hash functions overridden, different hash methods are called for `exists` and hash lookup. So in that scenario there can be a difference either in performance or behaviour.

Comment: I think this explanation is wrong. The original code replaces every false value with the value `0` - it probably wouldn't do that if it didn't have to.

Comment: @reinierpost: In the `grep` there is no replacements, just evaluation to true/false. It also does *not* alter every false value -  only when there is no key in `%sys`. If there was a value `$sys{'foo'} = undef;` or `$sys{'foo'} = '';` then it would not be changed to a `0`, but would still evaluate to `undef` or empty string in the block (if `@text` contained `'foo'`).

Comment: And as for "code I found on the internet" being probably correct? Perhaps if we knew the source there would be an explanation. My best guess is the caveat at the end of my answer. It is also possible the logic has been migrated from a `map` block where replacement to 0 was useful

Comment: @Jurafsky If this answer is the solution to your question, please take a moment to give it a check mark to close out the question.  Currently, none of your 9 questions have a selected answer.